# ESP.deepSleep() - over and over?

Tags: c++, nodemcu, sleep

Important note: the esp.deepsleep function uses microseconds, not milliseconds.

I posted another question [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/using-rtc-to-sleep-for-24hrs?noredirect=1#comment108100_52263) asking for clarification on how an RTC can be used to put a NodeMCU 12 to sleep for a long time (~24hrs or more).

This question concerns the use of ESP.deepSleep([microseconds]) with the NodeMCU 12 board.  There is a discussion [here](https://community.blynk.cc/t/esp-deep-sleep/5622/8) and I have followed the advice but have been unable to successfully implement the ESP.deepSleep() function using the Arduino IDE and a NodeMCU 12 board.

Initial findings:
-Connecting gpio16 (D0) to the RST pin causes a reset immediately upon entering sleep.  The entire boot process and loop are repeated over and over again.
-Simply using the ESP.deepSleep() function without gpio16-to-RST generates gibberish on the serial monitor and illuminates the red led on the board.

My code is here (I just drop "deepsleep();" where I want the sleep process to begin):

```
void deepsleep() {
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 1");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000); //1hr
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 2");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000); //2hr
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 3");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000); //3hr
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 4");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000); //4hr
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 5");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000); //5hr
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 6");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000); //6hr
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 7");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000); //7hr
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("sleeping hr 8");
  ESP.deepSleep(3600000, WAKE_RF_DEFAULT);  //8hr
}
```

What is wrong with this approach and why am I (apparently) causing an error?

Comment: just one point you may not be aware of ... the code you show suggests you think the ESP will continue on from after the deepsleep once it wakes up - that's not the case. after it wakes from deepsleep, it goes through the boot process (with a boot reason that indicates it has woken from sleep) - when you say "the entire boot process are repeated", do you mean immediately? or after 1 hour?

Comment: Immediate.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: well, that's not good - if it were after 1 hour, then the solution is easy, but immediate is problematic

Comment: What's the solution for the 1hr error?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Seeing as you say that the ESP isn't deep sleeping **at all**, then the question makes no sense

Comment: It's something that people may run into at some point and, if it's a simple answer, we are all better off knowing how to resolve it.  Even a simple explanation may get someone pointed in the right direction.

Comment: but that's not **your** problem - Anyway, the solution I'm speaking of regarding the code you posted is simply knowing that when a ESP awakes from deepsleep, it goes through full **boot** process, does not continue from where it left off. You can use `system_rtc_mem` to save some simple "state" so that when you boot, you know if this is an initial boot, or wake from deep sleep (and which deep sleep you've woken from) - [the guy with a swiss accent](https://github.com/SensorsIot/ESP8266-RTC-Memory) has some nice code examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a resistor between GPIO16 and RST. I usually use a 470 Ohm resistor. Shorting the pins with a wire does not work.

https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?t=14350#p64510

Maximum deep sleep is about 71 minutes. 3600000 microseconds = 3.6 seconds, not 1 hour. 1 hour in microseconds is 3600000000UL.

As mentioned in the comments, waking from deep sleep on the ESP8266 is a hardware reset so execution begins at the start of the setup function.

Comment: Every circuit for deep sleep I've ever seen has no resistor. I think the only issue was the sleep interval

Comment: inputs are high-impedance, so adding 470 ohms makes no practical diff

Comment: Yes, the linked-to topic is talking about *also* using an external method for resetting the board. In that case, you'll need a resistor, not when just connecting the GPIO to RST.